# Seeking a word with specific connotations of excessive, unashamed hypocrisy

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

There is a word, which I'm sure exists, but which has eluded me for the best part of a year; it's driven me so mad as to finally buckle and write this question in the hopes of drawing it out to the surface at last.

I'd tentatively define it as follows,

> Of a person's action or comment that is so hypocritical as to be unbelievable* that they'd try to take such a position.  *(The word itself could be used here to describe the unbelievably hypocritical behaviour)

The idiom, "That's rich (...coming from you)", sums up the sentiment, but if normal hypocritical behavior is rich, then the word I'm looking for is the mud-cake rich version of it.

Examples of situations where the word could be used to describe the (*insert word*) hypocritical nature,

1. A dubious politician takes a hard stance against a respected senior public servant for allegedly making misleading comments.
2. A social media influencer, who gains all their wealth from posting selfies to Instagram, has a go at society for its modern revelry in vanity.
3. A wealthy individual, who pays substantial sums to accountants to maximise what benefits they receive from government initiatives, criticises people with disabilities who receive government welfare.
4. One person, with extremely partisan political views, has a go at another person for their holding of their own extremely partisan political views.

An example sentence referencing an above scenario would be,

> Their behaviour was utterly (*insert word*).

I've searched through various thesauruses without luck (merriam-webster, wordhippo, Macquarie, ect.). Two words that keep blocking my mind's eye are incredulous and egregious; I believe the word in question likely sounds similar to these, therefore. However, these don't fit as it has to relate specifically to the demonstration of excessive hypocrisy which is unpalatably rich.

Comment: I'll suggest [Do Brits often use 'blag' where Americans use 'chutzpa' (for an extreme degree of impudence, gall)?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/286192/heres-one-for-the-brits-i-guess) as a duplicate. 'Effrontery' and 'brazenness' are offered. These don't stipulate hypocrisy, but I suspect most of the answers here won't, either.

Comment: ***sanctimonious*** nearly always implies ***hypocritical** sanctimony*.

Comment: You indicate that the word should be more complex (incredulous, egregious). Is **phony** in the right ballpark, in the sense of a fake or insincere sentiment?

Comment: If you are looking for a noun, one option is **effrontery**, which Merriam-Webster describes as "shameless, insolent disregard of propriety or courtesy." Other potentially relevant terms that MW suggests are **temerity** and **shameless audacity**, along with **nerve**, **cheek**, **gall**, and **chutzpah**.

Comment: @SvenYargs [effrontery](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/effrontery) does indeed seem the perfect fit – except that the sample sentence requires an adjective, and *effronterous* doesn't (yet) exist. [Of course, a slight cheat would be to say "Their behaviour was utter effrontery."] PS – I love the etymology of the word: from MW, "To the Romans, the shameless were "without forehead"!

Comment: what about "super-hypocritical"?

Answer (score 2):

How about

> pharisaical: marked by hypocritical censorious self-righteousness (Merriam-Webster, online)

or

> Pecksniffian
> unctuously hypocritical (Merriam-Webster, online)?

Comment: I don't think either of these is common in American English.

Comment: And, what does this have to do with anything? The questioner does not ask for common American English words.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering whether you're looking for *shameless*.

Comment: You should include a dictionary definition of the choosen word and also an explanation of why you think it's the best fit for the question.

Answer (score 0):

"Holier than thou attitude" is great to use for the expression "utter shameless hypocrisy". According to [Wiktionary](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/holier-than-thou):

> (derogatory) Hypocritically or self-righteously pious; sanctimonious

Comment: I think the question is aimed at getting a single word rather than a phrase.

Comment: And I also don't think 'holier than thou' is necessarily hypocritical.

Answer (score 0):

shameless and undisguised; barefaced.
BALD-FACED

Comment: These would be improved with dictionary definitions.